# How to display the controls where I want?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I would like to show the controls as in the image, but after I try ControlPlacement->Right and some combinations of Row[] and Column[], I can´t get the solution.

Could you help me?

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[{a, b, c, d}],

 Style["a and b in a column on the right", Orange, Bold],
 {{a, 1, "a->"}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{b, 1, "b->"}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Open"},
 Delimiter,

 Style["c and d in a column on the more right", Blue, Bold],
 {{c, 1, "c->"}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{d, 1, "d->"}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I am not aware how to achieve a setting like you do but perhaps you could look into `ControlPlacement->Right` ? This does move controls to the right but they are placed vertically one after another.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic yes, I tried but all the controls go to the Right in a ONLY column. I would like to obtain 2 cols.

Comment: You can use e.g. `Grid` together with `Control` to achieve complex layouts. I would recommend that you browse the [Demonstrations](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/)  website, which features many different types of control layouts together with the used code. [This one](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AnamorphicOrigami/) took me quite a while, layout-wise. It may be wise to consider the pareto rule in terms of effort invested...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Manipulate[None,

 Grid[{
   {Dynamic@ListPlot[{a, b, c, d}],
    Grid[{
      {Style["a and b in a column on the right", Orange, Bold]},
      {Control[{{a, 1, "a->"}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Open"}]},
      {Control[{{b, 1, "b->"}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Open"}]}
      }],
    Grid[{
      {Style["c and d in a column on the more right", Blue, Bold]},
      {Control[{{c, 1, "c->"}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Open"}]},
      {Control[{{d, 1, "d->"}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Open"}]}
      }]
    }
   }, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Center]

 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]